# TestNG groups depending on the same group. Which one should get executed first?

Tags: webdriver, testng

I have two test groups which are dependent on another group.

```
<dependencies>
    <group name="search" depends-on="login" />
    <group name="addnew" depends-on="login" />
</dependencies>
```

Which one out of the two groups (search, addnew) should ideally get executed first? For me, the group addnew is getting executed first all the time, which I don't want to happen. I want search to get executed and then addnew to get executed, once login is done. Also, I have set "preserve-order" for the test as true. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want search to get executed first, then add new is also dependent on search group in that case.  You can specify a list of groups in the depends-on list.  Try with depends-on="login search" or you can let search depend on login and make add new depend on search to guarantee execution order.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from documentation: "By default, TestNG will run your tests in the order they are found in the XML file. If you want the classes and methods listed in this file to be run in an unpredictible order, set the preserve-order attribute to false:"

```
<test name="Regression1" preserve-order="false">
```

```
<class name="test.Test1">
  <methods>
    <include name="m1" />
    <include name="m2" />
  </methods>
</class>

<class name="test.Test2" />
```